# Gradient overlay doesn't end nicely in the background color

Tags: css, sass, gradient, linear-gradients, compass

I'm using compass to overlay a gradient on an image. But the problem is that I want my gradient to end stronger so that the image just fades into the current background color.

This is my scss:

```
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('../images/MacBookAir.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    @include background-size(cover);

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.2), rgba(255,255,255,1));
    }
}
```

html is simply:

```
<div class="row hero"></div>
```

[image: Example]

It's hard to see since the background is white here also but I'm guessing since I'm ending my gradient in 100% white it should just fade into the background?

Can somebody help me with this or maybe provide a better(cleaner) solution in compass to get this done?

Comment: [A gradient generator, perhaps?](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) - esp. with a solid white colour ~80% instead of 100%

Comment: Nevermind I have searched some more but It seems impossible with current css3 unless you use a gradient mask(which is not crossbrowser friendly). I'll stuck to slicing up photoshop for this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so what I did, is actually give a height to your `&:before` so that it knows how tall it should go, while this might not be the most responsive choice, it works.

So your Sass would look like this:

```
.hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('http://placesheen.com/1200/500') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

&:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 508px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.2), rgba(255,255,255,1));
    }
}
```

The before wasn't reaching the full height, so it needs to extend 8 more pixels, thus `508px`. You could probably play with percentages as well to achieve the same effect.

I created a little tid bit on Sass Meister for you to take a look at, I wrapped it in a container just so it was easier to view in the Sass Meister tool...

http://sassmeister.com/gist/3528cb23d3e831231949

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take the image into photoshop and fade it out to a solid color? Seems to me like you're adding in code that doesn't need to be there. But if that isn't an option, and you must use a CSS gradient, you can always apply multiple gradients by separating the gradients with commas to darken it further since it already ends in 100%.